# How can I space evenly in both directions?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, expo, styled-components

I am developing a React Native app using Expo and I am using Styled Components.

At boot, it downloads a list of languages via an API and the flags of those languages are displayed on a selection screen.

I'm using flex-wrap so, right now, I have 6 languages, three rows, 2 flags in each row.

I am trying to figure out how to use flexbox so that the flags are spaced evenly in both directions.

I'm using flex-wrap and get even-spacing on the row.

How do I do the same column-wise, bearing in mind that the quantity of flags is dynamic?

I'd like the screen of languages to have even-spacing around the flags, both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Ill suggest you doing that via Dimensions,

```
const screenWidth  = Dimensions.get("window").width
```

Suppose you want to render `3` flags in a row and column can be `N`

so each Flag suppose takes up `const eachWidth = (screenWidth-(gutterSpace+marginHorizontal))/3`

Now so basically your `marginHorizontal` can be used as `marginVertical` so that all things are properly spaced.

const marginHorizontal = 20;
const gutterSpace = 10;

//Flag view

```
<View style={{width:eachWidth, margin:marginHorizontal}}/>
```

Hope it works, feel free for doubts

Answer (score -1):

Could adding `align-items: center` work? Perhaps also setting `height: 100vh` if you're making a selection screen.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>flag</div>
  <div>flag</div>
  <div>flag</div>
  <div>flag</div>
  <div>flag</div>
  <div>flag</div>
</section>
```

Comment: this is not react native